# Programmatically run webinspector on a page on Chrome and dump the output to a file

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to make chrome load a webpage and make it dump the output of the webinspector for that page ... all via commandline?

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to do with Chrome devtools. However, you can do similar things with [PhantomJs](http://phantomjs.org/). You can even do network sniffing and much more with PhantomJS. Check it out.